# Python vs Jython - MuleSoft

Tags: python, json

I have a Python script that converts JSON to CSV successfully when run in PyCharm.
When I move that Python script into a Python Transformer in MuleSoft, the script fails with the error:

> TypeError: unicode indices must be integers in  at line number 10 (javax.script.ScriptException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException). Message payload is of type: String

What is the difference between Python and Jython in this context? I don't get it!

Here is the Python:

```
import csv
import io

data = message.getInvocationProperty("my_JSON")

output = io.BytesIO()
writer = csv.writer(output)

for item in data:
    writer.writerow(([item['observationid'], item['fkey_observation'],  item['value'], item['participantid'], item['uom'], item['finishtime'], item['starttime'], item['observedproperty'], item['measuretime'], item['measurementid'], item['longitude'], item['identifier'], item['latitude']]))

result = output.getvalue()
```

`"my_JSON"` is a variable containing the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have forgotten to parse the JSON, like so: `data = json.loads(data)`.

Without that, `data` is a `str`, `item` is a `str` of length 1, and `item['observationid']` raises `TypeError`.